# Forbid a main method to be called

Tags: java, security, permissions, classloader

Hello I have implemented A Delegate pattern with ServiceLoader which basicly access different services from the classpath. So lets say I have jarA having a main method jarB holding the service loader and jarC with some services and jarD with some more services.

The problem is that the developers are abusing the pattern by implementing different main methods in different jars instead of having one client using the Delegate pattern to load the different services.

How can I make all main methods fail except one main method ?

Comment: why do you even include a `main`-method in the first place? That's not a requirement for a library...

Comment: You could probably try to find the main method that called your code in a stacktrace and fail if it's not the right one but I guess you should rather make the implementation notes clearer and fix the reason those developers do it wrong?